# Jasmine services behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have several jasmine test suites and some of them uses a service that I implemented. What are the services behavior in Jasmine. I noticed that when I'm running some tests against my service, what I'm doing affects to other unitTests. As we know this couldn't happen because unitTests must be completely independent. i.e.

```
it('Given my service with list populated when cleanList then getList return empty list', function(){
    myService.populateList(_myData_);
    expect(myService.getList().length).toBe(5);
    myService.cleanList();
    expect(myService.getList().length).toBe(0);
    expect(myService.getList()).toEqual([]);
});
```

If I execute that tests before another test in other describe in another completely different JS Script file my other test start to fails because I expect to use that list populated but this test has cleaned it. Are services here a singleton as in my app? Can I create independent instances of these services for each describe suite?

This is how I'm using these kind of services.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var _data_ = require('../../../../json/dataMock.json');

  fdescribe('MyApp wizard:', function(){
  var controller, createController;
  var modalInstance = { close: function(){}, dismiss: function(){} };
  var myService;


  beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('myapp.ui.apps.wizard');
    angular.mock.module('myapp.ui.apps.wizard.service');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $controller, $rootScope, _$sce_, _myService_){
    myService = _myService_;

    createController = function() {
        return $controller('MaintenancesWizardController', {
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $uibModalInstance: modalInstance,
            data: _data_,
            $sce: _$sce_,
            myService: _myService_
        });
    }
  }));

  it('this test fails if the one before is executed', function(){
    controller = createController();
    expect(myService.getList().length).toBe(5);
  });
```

Comment: are you trying to test the myservice? you can use a spy for your service so that it wont actually call the service and change the value.

Comment: @MukulJayaprakash I just discovered what happened! Read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered after couple of hours what happened. I was using require to import my mock data. When I use several imports I didn't remember that data is stored in memory. So my internal arrayList in the service was pointing to the same memory that my other describe suite. I used import for the same .json mock data file. I'm going to  change this and read it using 'fs'. From now on I recommend avoid using require in these cases.